# How pass values between controllers with a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to pass data between (I think) two child controllers. 
Trying to do this with a factory.

testFactory.js

```
          app= angular.module('testApp');
          app.factory('values', [function () {

    var testValues= {
        valueA: ''
    };

    return {
        setValueA: function(a) {
            testValues.valueA= a;
        },
        getValueA: function() {
            return testValues.valueA;
        }
    };
}]);
```

In different JS files so different controllers. 
controller1.js (this one sets the value)

```
angular.module('testApp')
    .controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope''values',
        function ( $scope, values) {

       values.setValueA("MyTestValue");

}]);
```

controller2.js this reads the value.

```
angular.module('testApp')
    .controller('secondCtrl', [ '$scope', 'values',
        function ( $scope, values) {

        $scope.valueA = values.getValueA();   

}]);
```

I include the js on the HTML side. Both controllers see the factory (I can see the functions during debugging). My problem is the second one doesn't have any values. Like its a brand new method.  Not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: There is no guarantee that `firstCtrl` will be fully initialized by the time `secondCtrl` is initialized, so the value set in `firstCtrl` may not be set.  The easiest (though maybe not best way) to get these values to sync is to use `$scope.$watch` on `values.getValueA();`

Comment: Yet tried to inject service (returned from factory) in firstCtrl and secondCtrl?

Answer (score 0):

```
The code Looks fine. I made a sample to replicate the same. working code is below



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <div>
      <h1>Services</h1>
      <div ng-controller="secondCtrl as list">
         <p ng-repeat="value in list.values">{{ value.valueA }}</p>
      </div>

      <div ng-controller="firstCtrl as post">
        <form ng-submit="post.addValue(post.newValue)">
          <input type="text" ng-model="post.newValue">
          <button type="submit">Add Message</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




   var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.factory('values', function(){

      var values = {};
      values.list = [];
      values.list.push({valueA: 'hellomessage'});
      values.add = function(message){
           values.list.push({valueA: message});
        };

      return values;
    });

    app.controller('firstCtrl', function (values){
      var self = this;
      self.newValue = 'First Value';
      self.addValue = function(value){

        values.add(value);
        self.newValue = '';
      };

    });

    app.controller('secondCtrl', function (values){
      var self = this;

      self.values = values.list;
    });
```

Comment: I don't doubt this works. My problem seems to be when I split it into different files things get lost. 
first.html  has a link to the factory with the script tag.
second.html also has to have a link to the factory with a script tag. 
Each Controller seems to initialize the factory back to new. 

Not sure how to call the factory so it doesn't get initialized each time.