# enableCellEditing in Angular-UI-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Please let me know if you didn't understand my approach. It's based on Angular-UI-grid. I have two controllers(ctrl1.js, ctrl2.js).I am getting data using get method on each controller from different webservices.

timeSeries is object in webservice(getTimeSeriesData) which I called in Ctrl1.js. 
There are 1500 objects in timeSeries and for last object(1500th) latest is true and for others latest is undefined. I should be able to edit(in ctrl2.js) only if latest is true, else user should not have any feature to edit the column.

Ctrl1.js Code

```
$rootScope.test = false;    
        $rootScope.latest = timeSeries.latest;
        if ($rootScope.latest == true){
            $rootScope.test = true;
            console.log($rootScope.test);
        } // everything is good here, I am getting true in console here.
```

To enable the cell editing I am using two approaches in Ctrl2.js:-(problem is here its not editable i.e cellEdit is false.)

```
 cellEditableCondition: function($rootScope){
                         return $rootScope.test
                         },

enableCellEdit: $rootScope.test;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Added an extra button click to display the value.

     <div>
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <div ng-controller="secondCtrl as second">

         <button type="submit" ng-click='second.getStatus()'>Add Message</button>
         <p> {{second.enableCellEdit}}</p>
      </div>

      <div ng-controller="firstCtrl as first">

      </div>
    </div>



   var app = angular.module('myapp', []);


    app.controller('firstCtrl', function ($rootScope){

        $rootScope.test = false;    
        $rootScope.latest = true;
        if ($rootScope.latest === true){
            $rootScope.test = true;
            console.log($rootScope.test);
        } 

    });

    app.controller('secondCtrl', function ($rootScope){
        var self = this;

         self.getStatus =function(){
           self.enableCellEdit = $rootScope.test;
         }


    });
```

If want to share the data between two different Controls on two different template use Factory is the better approach. Please refer to [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817069/how-pass-values-between-controllers-with-a-factory/46818707#46818707)
for factory data sharing.

Comment: I am not able to get the value in controller2 from controller1 using rootscope

Comment: Quite confusing statements. As per the description i did understood like you want to access the data that you set in Controller 1 (first Ctrl) in Controller 2 (Second Ctrl). If the same above solution works.  After running the solution on button click you can true value in controller 2 as its been set in Controller 1. Can you please elaborate more on what exactly you are looking for.